# How to call different constructors in class using single instance of that class in C#?

Tags: c#, class, constructor, instances

[Code description](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KLpf4W)

Here, I have created two classes Program in which Main() is present and Customer Class in which I have two Customer class constructors 1. without arguments 2. with arguments. How can i call the two constructors using single instance C1 of Customer class created in Main?

[Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KLpf4W)

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        Customer C1 = new Customer();
        C1.PrintFullName();
        C1 = new Customer();
        C1.PrintFullName();
    }
}

class Customer
{

    string _firstName;
    string _lastName;

    public Customer() : this("No firstname","No lastname")
    {
    }

    public Customer(string FirstName, string LastName)
    {
        this._firstName = FirstName;
        this._lastName = LastName;
    }

    public void PrintFullName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Full Name is {0}", this._firstName+" "+this._lastName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to call a constructor twice using the same instance? do you just want to reset the contents?

Comment: The parameterless constructor calls `: this("No firstname","No lastname")`, so you're already executing the _code_ of both constructors. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

A class constructor inherently is involved in *creating a new object* - so there is no inbuilt concept of running a constructor against an existing instance, unless you do some *very* nasty things that you shouldn't do.

If you want the ability to set all the properties *like* with a constructor, then perhaps add a method instead:

```
var obj = new SomeType();
obj.Init();
// ...
obj.Init("foo", "bar", 123);
// ...
```

Alternatively: just use the existing constructors and just accept that it'll be a different instance with a different reference:

```
var obj = new SomeType();
// ...
obj = new SomeType("foo", "bar", 123);
// ...
```

Comment: Okay. So to call different constructors in the class we only have the option of creating different instances . Can we use Singleton Pattern for this ?

Comment: @UV009 a singleton `Customer` sounds like a *terrible* idea, unless you're writing a client-side system that only runs in the context of a single `Customer`

Comment: @UV009 I think this is an x/y problem; you're asking about specific things like constructors and singletons, but you haven't told us *what you're actually trying to achieve*; so... it is very hard to comment

Comment: Yes. I am learning the concepts right now.  Thanks for your help.@Marc Gravell

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Customer C1 = new Customer("Bob", "Robert", "BobyBob 23, 41423");
        C1.PrintFullName();
        C1 = new Customer("Bob", "Robert");
        C1.PrintFullName();
    }
}

class Customer
{

    string _firstName;
    string _lastName;
    string _address;


    public Customer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm the last one :)");
        Console.WriteLine("Full Name is {0}", this._firstName+" "+this._lastName);
    }

    public Customer(string FirstName, string LastName) : this()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm gonna call the constructor within the same class that has no parameters.");      
        _firstName = FirstName;
        _lastName = LastName;
    }

    public Customer(string FirstName, string LastName, string address) : this(FirstName, LastName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm gonna call the constructor within the same class that has 2 parameters that are of type string.");
        _address = _address;
    }

    public void PrintFullName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Full Name is {0}", this._firstName+" "+this._lastName);
    }
}
```

Comment: it isn't at all clear to me how - if at all (which I suspect it doesn't) this answers the question at the top: "How can i call the two constructors using single instance C1 of Customer class created in Main?"

Comment: I think he wasn't sure how to put up the question since he might has not being familiar with the subject, so i assume he was referring to that.

Comment: This has helped me in understanding the concept. Thank you @Gilad Reich

Comment: @UV009 Glad it helped :)

Comment: I even Understood how this keyword works correctly by seeing the above code. @GiladReich